# SteamOS/Debian 8 disable Bluetooth/Wifi device

Tags: debian, hardware, steam

I have built in broken wifi and Bluetooth and I am using external adapters via usb. I have Installed SteamOS on an external hard drive. I can use the device manager to turn them off on windows but I have no idea how I can do that on SteamOS. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can't you disable it on your bios ?

Answer (score 0):

From the command line:

Turn on Wi-Fi:

```
nmcli radio wifi on
```

or:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Turn off Wi-Fi:

```
nmcli radio wifi off
```

or:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
```

Replace wlan0 with your wifi interface (see `ip a`). The `net-tools` is pre-installed on Debian 8.